# Psycopg2 relation db does not exist

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I recently started using Macbook because my laptop was changed at work and right after that I started having problems with some of my code that I use to upload a dataframe to a postgresql database.

```
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO

def create_connection(user,password):
    return psycopg2.connect(
    host='HOST',
    database='DBNAME',
    user=user,
    password=password)

conn = create_connection(user,password)

table = "data_analytics.tbl_summary_wingmans_rt"
buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(buffer, header=False, index=False)
buffer.seek(0)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.copy_from(buffer, table, sep=",", null="")
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

As you can see, the code is quite simple and even before the change of equipment it ran without major problem on Windows. But as soon as I run this same code on the mac it throws me the following error:

```
Error: relation "data_analytics.tbl_summary_wingmans_rt" does not exist
```

In several posts I saw that it could be the use of double quotes but I have already used the following and I still do not have a positive result.

```
"data_analytics."tbl_summary_wingmans_rt""
""data_analytics"."tbl_summary_wingmans_rt""
'data_analytics."tbl_summary_wingmans_rt"'
```

Comment: What version of psycopg2 are you using? The quoting behaviour of copy_from [changed in version 2.9](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of `copy_from` changed in psycopg2 2.9 to properly quote the table name, which means that you can no longer supply a schema-qualified table name that way; you have to use `copy_expert` instead.

Comment: This is insane, but correct! 

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate schema and table before sending it to Postgres parser now,
when you are sending `"data_analytics.tbl_summary_wingmans_rt"` its a single string and unable to parse

use `'"data_analytics"."tbl_summary_wingmans_rt"'` this will parse the output as "schema"."table" and PostgreSQL will be able to parse

Comment: I try it and keep getting the same error Error: relation ""data_analytics"."tbl_summary_wingmans_rt"" does not exist

Comment: @Kev : I get the same problem. The psycopg2 documentation for 2.9 says that if you have to specify a schema then to use copy_expert( ..) . It doesn't say that quoting the schema will work.